# MVC4 WebGrid and Ajax Pagination

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple question (may not be a simple answer!) with the WebGrid in MVC4.

I have a functional Grid like so

```
<div id="Submitted">
    @Html.Grid(
        Model.Submitted, displayHeader: false, fieldNamePrefix: "Submitted_", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "Submitted",
        columns: new WebGridColumn[]{
        new WebGridColumn(){ ColumnName = "Date",Header = "Date",Style = "",CanSort = false,Format = x => x.Date.ToString(Globals.Default.DATEFORMAT) },
        new WebGridColumn(){ ColumnName = "ID",Header = "Review",Style = "", CanSort = false, Format = x=>@Html.ActionLink("Review","Review","Company",new{ID = x.ID },new{})  }
    })
</div>
```

When reloading the "Submitted" div with Ajax when the next page button is clicked, it generates the next page fine - but it's going to  the original action on the controller, which should be a full page.

How does it filter out everything other than the grid itself? with some clever C# code or jQuery?

EDIT:
To clarify, I'm not asking how to do the paging better, or myself, as far as I'm concerned the default paging with the webgrid is working perfectly as it should - I'm asking how the WebGrid does it's ajax paging when posting back to an action which is returning a FULL page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this using jquery load() and functionality that allows it to select just the relevant incoming nodes. This is taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

> To allow the script to be applied just to a WebGrid, it uses jQuery selectors to identify elements with the ajaxGrid class set. The script establishes click handlers for the sorting and paging links (identified via the table header or footer inside the grid container) using the jQuery live method (api.jquery.com/live). This sets up the event handler for existing and future elements that match the selector, which is handy given the script will be replacing the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your grid in a partialview and update it by Ajax. In controller you should find the request's type. If it is a ajax request(by Request.IsAjaxRequest() ) you must return the partialview, otherwise you must return the original view.

If you are using ajax.beginform you must do something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "searchFailed", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Submitted" }))
    {
    ...
    }

<div id="Submitted">
   @Html.Partial("_partialviewname", Model)    
</div>
```

rn
and in controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
      ...
      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
          return PartialView("_partialviewname", db.model)  
         }
      return View(db.model)

    }
```

Comment: While this is an alternative, it has nothing to do with the question.
This could be a solution if my original question proves the WebGrid way is inefficient

Comment: @m.t.bennett, Ok I think I misunderstood your question. If you want to just load your grid each time, you must put it in a partialview. Is this your case?

Comment: Functionally my code is working and displaying as it should. My question is about how it manages to strip all content from the page and just return the webgrid on the ajax request

Comment: Your still not understanding me, i want to know how the webgrid functions on its ajax postback, not how to MAKE it function.

Comment: For instance, its ajax postback goes to the original action, which returns a full page view, but it only shows up as the next page in the grid rather than the full page with the next page